# Is it possible to connect two pipes/sockets?

Tags: c, sockets, unix, pipe, file-descriptor

I am wondering if it is possible to connect two pipes or socket. Lets suppose that have two pipes/socketpairs. The first one has two file descriptors A and B, the second one has two file descriptors C and D. Is it possible to connect B to C to be able to write to A and read the data from D? Other then just reading form B and writing to C in user space?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to read from one socket and write to another without copying the data to user-space, look at http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendfile .  You need a fairly recent Linux.

Comment: Actually, I use FreeBSD but it's implemented. I will read about this. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it allows to send data from one file descriptor to another without copying it to the user space. However, it doesn't connect two pipes/sockets permanently. Therefore, I think I will send B file descriptor to the other process instead of passing data through C - D pipe. Many thanks.

Comment: Then it is splice http://linux.die.net/man/2/splice that you want and not sendfile. However I don't know if it exists on FreeBSD